# My keyboard recordings sound tinny/low quality

Tags: audio, recording, sound, keyboard, quality

I’ve recently started recording piano covers for Youtube. I use a USB and Audacity to record the audio. However, when I play it back on my computer it sounds more tinny or lower quality than my keyboard sounds. Can anyone suggest ways I can improve the quality? If you want to listen so you can understand more, here’s the link to a video,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the recording sounds perfectly "within acceptable parameters" on my studio monitors, maybe either your piano sound in the room is 'too fat' & you have just got used to how it sounds... or your computer speakers sound 'too thin'.

<sup>*This is intentionally vague, because we can't actually hear either source in the same way you do.*</sup>

If you are using a laptop, this is not in any way surprising.

An investment in at least basic external speakers would be the first step in a long road towards sonic quality.

Comment: This past Christmas I finally got reference monitors for my speakers, and as @Tetsujin states, it sounds like a very classic piano voice with it's full range.  Notably, listening on my wife's laptop which has pretty good speakers, (read: non-generic but built in) it is still very "hollow" in comparison.